# Create multiple UIViews dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I want to create a bar chart using `UIView` animations. The bar chart will be dynamically created, using data retrieved from my persistent store.

To teach myself how to use `UIView` animations, I followed [this Ray Wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-uiview-animation) then built a modified app based on it. As a result, I feel comfortable with the animation aspects--at least as long as it involves discrete (Storyboard-created) views specified by hard-coded data.

However, in the full implementation, the bar chart will have multiple columns, the number, heights, widths, etc. of which will be specified proportionally by live data.

At this point, I've created a UIView in the storyboard, linked to a custom UIView subclass called `RiserBar`, thinking to create instances of the views (`RiserBar *`) on the fly. However--and I feel kinda dumb admitting it--I realize I don't really know how to implement this idea. For example, if I'm iterating through an array containing the specifications for several bars, what would that look like? Would each bar have a name? How would those names be generated?

Here's the code I'm thinking about. `aBAr` is an instance variable. The `frame` specification, as well as `specArray` are just dummies, as the exact specification mechanism isn't clear just yet, but the idea is to create as many `RiserBar` objects as there are entries in `specArray`:

```
-(void) makeBarChart
{
    RiserBar *aBar;
    for (int i=0; i<specArray.count; i++)
    {
        aBar = [[RiserBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        aBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [self.view addSubview:aBar];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                              delay:.2
                            options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^
         {
             aBar.frame = CGRectMake(50, self.view.frame.origin.y, startingSpec.width, startingSpec.height);
             aBar.frame = CGRectMake(50, self.view.frame.origin.y, endSpec.width, endSpec.height);
         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {
             NSLog(@"Done!");
         }];

    }
}
```

Please help me straighten out my thinking about this!

Thanks!

Comment: Just sharing : it worked well for me for various graphs, may be helpful to you.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/13269/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-1

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out, and may use it. However, I went the roll your own route here because several chart libraries I looked at (well actually Pie Chart libraries) were sparsely commented, my needs seemed simple, and I figured I'd learn something.